# Get length of text in div using div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div with fixed width of 30%.
I want to get the length of text in that div.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4M8V7/)

What i am doing here is ,

```
var text=$('#test').text();
text=text.trim();
var len=text.length;
alert(text);
alert(len);
```

I am getting length of only text . How can i get length of text after applying html tags to it.

**Current behaviour : Getting length as 105.

Expected behaviour : 29 * total line** [ 29 is atmost characters can be in line of div ]

***Update***

I also want to to count the length including the area (green) shown in following image. 
[image]

Comment: It works fine for me, it's alerting length : 31 , counted the text and the text length is 31

Comment: And what if we added <br> tag to it

Comment: This fiddle is with <br> tags http://jsfiddle.net/4M8V7/3/ alerts 31

Comment: Do you mean you want to count the br tags as characters? The fiddle seems to be working correctly..

Comment: If you want to count the br tags aswell you must use .html() not text()

Comment: alert is cmg just fine in ur fiddle (with br tags as well)

Comment: If we add <br> to text it will break the line , want to add all the white space after it.

Comment: **Note:** In your fiddle you forgot to close the `<div>` thus creating two divs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/4M8V7/7/

```
//With html length
console.log( $.trim($('#test').html()).length );

//Without html length
console.log( $.trim($('#test').text()).length );
```

Comment: So you are looking for how much text can be adjusted in a div? If you put a lot of iiiiiiiiiiiii you will get more text so I don't think so there is any way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

use `.html()` instead of `.text()` to count also `<br>` tags [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/semir/4M8V7/5/)